# How to prepend/insert an element into a jsonb array in PostgreSQL 12?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

Example:

```
drop table a;
create table a( value jsonb);
insert into a values ('{"items":[0,1,2]}'::jsonb);
select value->'items' from a;
```

I already know how to append to an array. For example:

```
select jsonb_build_object('items', 
        value->'items' || '3'::jsonb
)  from a
```

This returns:

```
{"items": [0, 1, 2, 3]}
```

But I don't know how to **preprended** or **insert** an element into an array.

For example:

```
select jsonb_build_object('items', 
        jsonb_array_insert(value->'items',0,-1)
)  from a
```

And this would return:

```
{"items": [-1, 0, 1, 2]}
```

But there is no `jsonb_array_insert` function. The documentation at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html ( Table 9.45. Additional jsonb Operators ) describes some useful jsonb operators, but none of them can be used for inserting/prepending elements.

Well, `jsonb_array_elements(value->'items')` can be used to convert an array into a set of elements. But I don't see how it could be used to insert/prepend elements into the array.

I could possibly write my own PL/SQL function for this, but there must be a better way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSONB_INSERT` to achieve what you want. Please refer the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html).

Try it this way:

```
select 
jsonb_insert(value,'{items,0}','-1'::jsonb)
from a
```

This function works exactly as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the concatenation operator to prepend elements to a jsonb array simply by switching the order of the operands (note that in order for the concatenation to work in this case the right-hand operand needs to be wrapped in parentheses):

```sql
select jsonb_build_object('items',
        '-1'::jsonb || (value->'items')
)  from a;
```

This returns:

```sql
{"items": [-1, 0, 1, 2]}
```

One benefit of this method is that you can use it to prepend multiple elements at a time:

```sql
select jsonb_build_object('items',
        '[-2, -1]'::jsonb || (value->'items')
)  from a;
```

This returns:

```sql
{"items": [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]}
```

This doesn't handle the case where you want to insert elements at an arbitrary index.

Comment: Just found this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/224232